# Unit testing rethinkdb based flask app, connections overriden

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, rethinkdb

I'm writing unittests for my flask app that employs a rethinkdb backend. A new connection is opened and closed before and after each request as given below:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    ARGS = settings.RETHINKDB_ARGS
    try:
        g.rdb_conn = rethinkdb.connect(host=ARGS['host'],
                               port=ARGS['port'],
                               db=ARGS['db'])
    except RqlDriverError:
        abort(503, "Database connection could be established.")

@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    try:
        g.rdb_conn.close()
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

I'm creating database records on each test

```
def setUp(self):
        self.app = current_app.test_client()
        self.user = User.create({
                                'email': 'a@a.com',
                                'first_name': 'a',
                                'last_name': 'a',
                                'role': 'user',
                                'status': 'active'


                           })
```

User.create is basically calling

```
r.table('user').insert(data).run(g.rdb_conn)
```

My test functions:

```
 def test_get(self):

        url = url_for('api.get_user', **{'id': self.user.data.id})
        retval = ujson.loads(self.app.get(url).data)
        ...
 def test_get2(self):
        ...
```

When the tests run, this is what happens:

1. setup runs for the first time, say g.rdb_conn = 1
2. test_get run, g.rdb_conn is overriden, g.rdb_conn = 2 and is closed after request ends
3. setup run for the second time for test_get2 with g.rdb_conn = 2, but it's already closed at the end of the previous request
4. "ReqlDriverError: Connection is closed." thrown

How can i prevent the connections overriding eachother on each test run?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, my problem is not directly related to rethinkdb, but flask global variable, that is modified everytime a request done, being overriden.

I've solved it using mock library.

```
from mock import patch
...
rdb_conn = rethinkdb.connect(...)

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
...
    @patch('flask.g.rdb_conn', rdb_conn)
    def setUp(self):
        functions that depend on g.rdb_conn...
```